# How to query distinct column value when query all row data

Tags: jqgrid

I hava one MySQL Table

```
id  name   birthdate   city  
 1  Owen   2011/01/01  USA
 2  Mark   2012/05/01  UK
 3  Marry  2011/01/01  JP
 4  John   2011/01/01  JP
```

First，I uesd jqgrid to read all row data. But Now,I want to know when birthdate=2011/01/01，how many different city in the table.
Can don't used sql，only used jqgrid plugin?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `distinct` function.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(city) FROM table WHERE birthday = "2011/01/01";
```